# Perfect hash function for strings known in advance

Tags: c++, string, hash, perfect-hash

I have 4000 strings and I want to create a perfect hash table with these strings. The strings are known in advance, so my first idea was to use a series of `if` statements:

```
 if (name=="aaa")
      return 1;
 else if (name=="bbb")
      return 2;
        .
        .
        .
 // 4000th `if' statement
```

However, this would be very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you know all the strings a priori, are you sure you need to hash them?

Comment: I need to store a graph as a adjacency list so I guess hash table is required.@NPE

Comment: Hashing is the most efficient way to do this for that many strings, if you have a priori information about your strings you can create a good hashing function by using something like gperf.

Answer (score 12):

[`gperf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) is a tool that does exactly that:

> GNU `gperf` is a perfect hash function generator. For a given list of strings, it produces a hash function and hash table, in form of C or C++ code, for looking up a value depending on the input string. The hash function is perfect, which means that the hash table has no collisions, and the hash table lookup needs a single string comparison only.

According to the documentation, `gperf` is used to generate the reserved keyword recogniser for lexers in GNU C, GNU C++, GNU Java, GNU Pascal, GNU Modula 3, and GNU indent.

The way it works is described in [GPERF: A Perfect Hash Function Generator](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/gperf.pdf)  by Douglas C. Schmidt.

Comment: I think it is too much for my application, I prefer simpler thing

Comment: I'll bookmark this thread to see your perfect solution that is simpler than gperf.

Comment: A runtime solution may be easier to *build*. This library is apparently more efficient memory-wise: http://cmph.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8):

Better later than never, I believe this now finally answers the OP question:

Simply use https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen -- a Compile-time (constexpr) library of immutable containers for C++ (using "perfect hash" under the hood).

On my tests, it performed in pair with the famous GNU's **gperf** perfect hash C code generator.

On your pseudo-code terms:

```
#include <frozen/unordered_map.h>
#include <frozen/string.h>

constexpr frozen::unordered_map<frozen::string, int, 2> olaf = {
    {"aaa", 1},
    {"bbb", 2},
    .
    .
    .
    // 4000th element
};

return olaf.at(name);
```

Will respond in ***O(1)*** time rather than OP's *O(n)*
-- O(n) assuming the compiler wouldn't optimize your if chain, which it might do)

Answer (score 6):

Since the question is still unanswered and I'm about to add the same functionality to my HFT platform, I'll share my inventory for **Perfect Hash Algorithms in C++**. It is harder than I thought to find an open, flexible and bug free implementation, so I'm sharing the ones I didn't drop yet:

- The CMPH library, with a collection of papers and such algorithms -- https://git.code.sf.net/p/cmph/git
- BBHash, one more implementation from a paper's author -- https://github.com/rizkg/BBHash
- Ademakov's -- another implementation from the paper above -- https://github.com/ademakov/PHF
- wahern/phf -- I'm currently inspecting this one and trying to solve some allocation bugs it has when dealing with C++ Strings on huge key sets -- https://github.com/wahern/phf.git
- emphf -- seems unmantained -- https://github.com/ot/emphf.git

Answer (score 3):

I believe @NPE's answer is very reasonable, and I doubt it is *too much for your application* as you seem to imply.

Consider the following example: suppose you have your "engine" logic (that is: your application's functionality) contained in a file called `engine.hpp`:

```
// this is engine.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
void standalone() {
  std::cout << "called standalone" << std::endl;
}
struct Foo {
  static void first() {
    std::cout << "called Foo::first()" << std::endl;
  }
  static void second() {
    std::cout << "called Foo::second()" << std::endl;
  }  
};
// other functions...
```

and suppose you want to dispatch the different functions based on the map:

```
"standalone" dispatches void standalone()
"first" dispatches Foo::first()
"second" dispatches Foo::second()
# other dispatch rules...
```

You can do that using the following gperf input file (I called it "lookups.gperf"):

```
%{

#include "engine.hpp"

struct CommandMap {
    const char *name;
    void (*dispatch) (void);
};

%}

%ignore-case
%language=C++
%define class-name Commands
%define lookup-function-name Lookup
struct CommandMap

%%
standalone, standalone
first, Foo::first
second, Foo::second
```

Then you can use gperf to create a `lookups.hpp` file using a simple command:

```
 gperf -tCG lookups.gperf > lookups.hpp
```

Once I have that in place, the following `main` subroutine will dispatch commands based on what I type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "engine.hpp" // this is my application engine
#include "lookups.hpp" // this is gperf's output

int main() {

  std::string command;

  while(std::cin >> command) {
    auto match = Commands::Lookup(command.c_str(), command.size());
    if(match) {
      match->dispatch();
    } else {
      std::cerr << "invalid command" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Compile it:

```
 g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

and run it:

```
$ ./a.out
standalone
called standalone
first
called Foo::first()
Second
called Foo::second()
SECOND
called Foo::second()
first
called Foo::first()
frst
invalid command
```

Notice that once you have generated `lookups.hpp` your application has no dependency whatsoever in gperf.

Disclaimer: I took inspiration for this example from [this site](http://www.stev.org/post/2012/06/16/Using-gperf-with-C++.aspx).