# Bijection from string to int aka reversible hash

Tags: c++, hash, c++20

I need to convert a set of strings similar to `/azurite/spot00` to integers in order to use in ML libraries. Hand-rolling an enumerating algorithm (assign i++ to each next label) sounds easy enough. But nowhere nearly as elegant as a bidirectional hash between `std::string` and `int` (not sure if I need `int64` or something else).

`std::hash` doesn't seem to state it's reversible. Anything in the standard library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694153/perfect-hash-function-for-strings-known-in-advance

Comment: Elegance is not objective. What's wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general-purpose way to find a bijection from `std::string` to `int` for the simple but mundane reason that there are more possible `std::string`s than there are `int`s. (Specifically, there's effectively an unbounded number of possible `std::string`s, and there are only 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> distinct possible integers).

There are ways to construct perfect hash functions from strings to integers if you have a fixed set of strings you want to work with, but in your case if the goal is just to label all the strings with distinct values your initial idea of just having a counter and assigning each string the next available number is probably just fine.

Comment: there is `std::string::max_size`, but yeah practically only bounded by available memory

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yep, hence "effectively" an unbounded number of strings :-)

Comment: Or just limit your program to only supporting strings whose length is less than `sizeof(int)`  :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, my alphabet is "lowercase latin letters and / and digits". So the size is 39. In 64 bits I think one can encode 12 characters from that alphabet. Which is almost enough. But not worth the hassle.